# how to add image and text in pdf for save html file

Tags: java, itext

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.codec.Base64.OutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.URL;

public class myclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String result = "<html><body><div>(i) the recognised association shall have the approval of the Forward  Markets  Commission established under the Forward  Contracts (Regulation) Act, 1952 (74 of 1952) in respect of trading in derivatives and shall function in accordance with the guidelines or conditions laid down by the Forward  Markets  Commission; </div>  <body> </html>";
        Document document = new Document();
        OutputStream file = null;
        try {
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(
                    "E://Image.pdf"));
            document.open();
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
            document.open();
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
            htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(result));
            String imageUrl = "http://www.taxmann.com/emailer/demo/mobileAapp/newAppDesign.jpg";
            Image image2 = Image.getInstance(new URL(imageUrl));
            document.add(image2);
            document.close();
            file.flush();
            document.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to save image and text in pdf file. When we set Either text or image then it's working fine, simultaneously am not able to save image and text Both in pdf. How will I save image and text both in Pdf? I am Using **iText**.

Answer (score 0):

May the problem is Wrong import for `Outputstream` and `file` is Always null . You never assigned any O/P strream.

Try this

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.URL;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class ItextExample {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String result = "<html><body><div>(i) the recognised association shall have the approval of the Forward  Markets  Commission established under the Forward  Contracts (Regulation) Act, 1952 (74 of 1952) in respect of trading in derivatives and shall function in accordance with the guidelines or conditions laid down by the Forward  Markets  Commission; </div>  <body> </html>";
        Document document = new Document();
        OutputStream file = null;
        try {
            file = new FileOutputStream("E://Image1.pdf");
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document,file);
            document.open();
            HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
            htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(result));
            String imageUrl = "http://www.taxmann.com/emailer/demo/mobileAapp/newAppDesign.jpg";
            Image image2 = Image.getInstance(new URL(imageUrl));
            document.add(image2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
            document.close();
            file.flush();
            }catch(Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();  
            }
        }
    }
}
```